# How can I make an Outlook 2010 rule fire for a new message before it is identified as Junk and put in the Junk E-mail folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, spam-prevention, email-filter

I'm running Outlook 2010 against Exchange 2010.

There are some messages that Outlook identifies as junk (or perhaps it's Exchange identifying them as junk, because I know that with Exchange 2010 and Outlook, if Exchange identifies the message as spam it will cause the message to be placed in my "Junk E-Mail" folder - in other words, it may not be Outlook making the decision) and appropriately places in the Junk E-Mail folder.

I would like to create rules to act on those messages before they hit the junk folder.  By default, the junk designation seems to take precedent.  I then tried classifying the messages as "Not Junk" when they were in the Junk E-Mail folder, but it appears that all that happens is the email address is whitelisted (yet the messages were classified as junk by some different heuristic).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The junk folder does take precedent, to keep rules from accidentally moving things out of Junk. New (feature? debateable) in 2007.

I know of no way to automatically run a rule before the Junk classification, but you can now run rules with VBA scripting. A quick google search revealed this VBA example (Runs all rules with Junk in the name with one button click on the junk folder): http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/junkrules.htm

You might be able to run the script automatically with the "Run a script" rule too--not sure about that.

Comment: Good find re: that article.  Nuts though...  Any thoughts on me telling Outlook that the message is not junk?  I don't understand why it appears that Outlook uses various rules to determine that the message is junk but when I mark it as "not junk" it only seems to whitelist the address, which keeps changing anyway.

Comment: My answer to that question involves a lot of four letter words and astericks. I always just disable the outlook junk mail filter entirely. You can also whitelist domains (I do my entire work domain(s)). Do both by clicking the junk folder, then the down arrow next to the small junk button on the ribbon, then playing with the options or safesenders.

Comment: Worse case you can add yourself to the "safe recipients" list. Might have to deal with some spam though.