# In Outlook 2010, whitelist messages based on subject

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, spam-prevention

On a business website, I have several web forms that send me an e-mail message when they are submitted.  However, in Outlook 2010, these form submissions often got put in the Junk folder.  To solve this problem, I put a code word in the subject of the e-mails that get sent.  (For example, let's say that the subject of each form submission message contains the word `myform`.)  What I want to do is whitelist any message that comes in that contains `myform` in the subject.

I had set up a rule that does this:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
with myform in the subject
mark it as high importance
 and move it to the Inbox folder
```

This used to work, but now it seems that Outlook is not applying rules to any message that it considers junk.  If I send myself a message that contains `myform`, it gets marked as high importance (so I know the rule is running), but if I submit the form, the message stays in the junk folder and does not get marked as high importance.

Is there any way that I can whitelist a message based on subject, to keep it out of the Junk folder?  Perhaps there is a way that I can instruct Outlook to run rules on the Junk messages?

Also, is there any way that I can tell why Outlook considers these messages Junk?

Comment: I just found this: http://superuser.com/q/530111/245988 So perhaps this is not possible, but I'd still appreciate any insight that anyone can provide.